# Setup Response Header in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, iis

I want to configure the following security header in SharePoint, however every time I do so, either at the site- or web-config-level, these headers end up being duplicated. Any suggestions?

```
<add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
<add name="Cache-Control" value="max-age=0" />
```

[image]

How I can make Content-Security-Policy more secure?

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' data: gap: *Domain removed* 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' *Domain removed* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';  media-src *" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding custom header on your web.config like this path and value is example down below:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Header_Name" value="Headr_Value" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

</system.webServer>

If custom header not fix this you can put or change header in Custom Http Module. In this case you can manage all data in responses.​

Comment: Thanks Victor for the suggestion. I already tried what you suggested with respect to web.config.

 Custom Http Module changes, is this related to changes in code?

Comment: I think Yes because you have full control of response and can adding what you need.