# Want to enable Cache-Control response header in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to enable Cache-Control response header in SharePoint 2013 but unfortunately I am not abel to set it up. I tried two methods

- Tried with HTTP Response header at site level but it duplicating. ([Setup Response Header in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308321/setup-response-header-in-sharepoint/))
- Tried with URLRewrite but after enabling the rule, Login functionality is not working.